# Display accessibility reports in a concise way

Tags: info-visualisation, data-tables, data

The following is meant to be full screen on a website like a dashboard.

I have accessibility reports for different webpages.

Which gives accessibility scores and mark them as critical or serious and so on based on scores.

Also further to that, display additional issue details on what exactly a particular issue was.

And a link to go to the exact page.

And a button to refresh the accessibility scan numbers.

Problem is that for each page, I need to account for desktop, tablet and mobile accessibility scans.

And the report figures are Critical, Serious Major, Minor.

I then need to expand on the issue details for each report figure.

This ends up as 3 x 4 x 4 + (2 more columns for link and button) total columns if I am doing the math right.

That's a lot of columns and it ends up quite messy. And will end up needing horizontal scrolling to see more details.

Is there a more cleaner way to present this?

I am using a table here but I am not tied to it.

Just looking for a good way to present this data.

This is an example.

I didn't even place in all the columns and as can see it is already too long and clunky.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of accessibility tools and how they report the results, so you can do some research and see whether they suit your purpose.

Some of the well known tools include the [axe accessibility tools](https://www.deque.com/axe/) from Deque Systems or the Google Chrome Lighthouse tool (which is based on the axe tool but presented in a different way), and there are a whole list of other accessibility tools that can be found on the [w3.org website](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tools/).